# WPF MVVM VM is binding to View but RelayCommand is not executing as expected

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm working on a WPF application and am having some trouble handling a new window.

I have a Page "ScriptsPage" and associated VM shown below.

```
<Page
    x:Class="Heimdall.Views.Pages.ScriptsPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:helpers="clr-namespace:Heimdall.Helpers"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Heimdall.Views.Pages"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:ui="http://schemas.lepo.co/wpfui/2022/xaml"
    Title="ScriptsPage"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:ScriptsPage,
                                     IsDesignTimeCreatable=False}"
    d:DesignHeight="450"
    d:DesignWidth="800"
    ui:Design.Background="{DynamicResource ApplicationBackgroundBrush}"
    ui:Design.Foreground="{DynamicResource TextFillColorPrimaryBrush}"
    Foreground="{DynamicResource TextFillColorPrimaryBrush}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid>        
        <ui:Card Grid.Row="0">

            <DockPanel>
                <DockPanel Margin="0,0,0,10" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" Text="Python Scripts" Margin="0,0,30,0"/>
                    <ui:Button  
                        Content="Upload Script" 
                        Command="{Binding ViewModel.CreateScriptCommand, Mode=OneWay}" 
                        Margin="0,0,3,0"></ui:Button>
                </DockPanel>
                <ui:Card>
                    <ListView>
                        
                    </ListView>
                </ui:Card>
            </DockPanel>

        </ui:Card>
        
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

```
public partial class ScriptsViewModel : ObservableObject, INavigationAware
{
    //Trimmed down to relevant code

    public ScriptSettingsWindowViewModel? ScriptsSettingsWindowViewModel { get; private set; }

    [RelayCommand]
    private void OnCreateScript()
    {
        var scriptSettingsWindow = new ScriptSettingsWindow(ScriptsSettingsWindowViewModel, SelectedScript, SaveScript);
        scriptSettingsWindow.Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow;
        scriptSettingsWindow.Show();
    }


}
```

This button works properly and a new ScriptSettingsWindow is spawned. The problem occurs in the created window.

```
<ui:FluentWindow 
        x:Class="Heimdall.Views.Windows.ScriptSettingsWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:ui="http://schemas.lepo.co/wpfui/2022/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Heimdall.Views.Windows"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="ScriptSettingsWindow" Height="500" Width="400"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:ScriptSettingsWindow,
                               IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
        ui:Design.Background="{DynamicResource ApplicationBackgroundBrush}"
        ui:Design.Foreground="{DynamicResource TextFillColorPrimaryBrush}"
        ExtendsContentIntoTitleBar="True"
        Foreground="{DynamicResource TextFillColorPrimaryBrush}"
        WindowBackdropType="Mica"
        WindowCornerPreference="Round"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

    <Window.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <DockPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="Upload Script: " />
                <Button Content="Upload" Command="{Binding ViewModel.UploadFileCommand, Mode=OneWay}" />
            </DockPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</ui:FluentWindow>
```

```
public partial class ScriptSettingsWindowViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private bool _isInitialized = false;
    public ScriptSettings ScriptSettings { get; private set; }

    [ObservableProperty]
    private Action<ScriptSettings> saveChangesAction;

    public string WindowTitle = "Script Settings";
    private ScriptSettings _scriptSettings;

    private Action<ScriptSettings> _cancelScriptAction;

    [RelayCommand]
    private void UploadFile()
    {
        OpenFileDialog fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        fileDialog.DefaultExt = ".py"; // Required file extension 
        fileDialog.Filter = "Python Script (.py)|*.py"; // Optional file extensions
        fileDialog.ShowDialog();

    }


    public ScriptSettingsWindowViewModel(ScriptSettings settings, Action<ScriptSettings> saveChangesAction)
    {
        ScriptSettings = settings;
        SaveChangesAction = saveChangesAction;
        

    }
}
```

I expect this to work like a normal view/viewModel binding.

Checking the runtime values in for the view it appears to be binding correctly.

But the UploadFile RelayCommand will not execute at all.

I've tested a couple other relaycommands with debug messages and same thing, no relay command will execute from the newly created window.

Anyone know what's going on here? I've been trying to learn MVVM and WPF for the last couple months and am picking it up I think but so far everything has existed in a single window, using a navigation service to change views. I could integrate the ScriptSettings window into the current view but the flexibility of a new window feels better to me and is what my users would be familiar with.

Thank you

Comment: I didn't see where you set the `DataContext` for both windows. Most likely the second window has no `DataContext` set or the data context is wrong (wrong type, no `ViewModel` property set and so on).

Comment: DataContext is set in window definition:

'''d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:ScriptSettingsWindow,
                               IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"'''

Comment: `d:DataContext` is design-only thing, it does not affect the runtime at all because it is ignored by the compiler due to `mc:Ignorable="d"`. So you should set the `DataContext` for the runtime somewhere else.

Comment: In MVVM a dialog *must* be handled in the view and not in the view model. A dialog is a control, a UI element with the only purpose to interact with a user. UI and user are both nonexistent in the context of the view model. The view model is UI and user agnostic. You must show the dialog in the view (code-behind, attached behavior etc.) and then pass the result to the view model (e.g. via data binding or by calling a method on the view model class). And don't forget to set the runtime DataContext from the constructor of the MainWindow. You only declared a designtime instance.

Comment: See the [Interaction-Pattern from ReactiveUI](https://www.reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/interactions/#an-example)

Comment: Can you please show the constructor of ScriptSettingsWindow and how the ScriptsSettingsWindowViewModel parameter is used?